# How to add Azure SQL connection string to the App Configuration Service using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create an Azure SQL Database using Terraform.

After that, I need to create an Azure App Config Service to store the connection string generated by the Azure SQL Database.

After some research, I found that it can be achieved in two different ways.

1.- Generating a variable with the connection string

```
output "database_name" {
  value = azurerm_sql_database.database.name,
  database_connection_string    = "Server=tcp:${module.database.name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=${module.database.database_name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=${var.database_user};Password=${var.database_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}
```

2.- By using local-exec command to get the connection string and then put it into the Azure App Config Service

```
locals {
  config_mapping = {
    mykey = "myvalue",
    CONFIG_CN_ACCOUNT = "myvalue"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "example" {
  for_each = local.config_mapping

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az appconfig kv set --connection-string $CONNECTION_STRING --key $KEY --value $VALUE --yes"

    environment = {
      CONNECTION_STRING = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.primary_write_key.0.connection_string
      KEY               = each.key
      VALUE             = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add the Azure SQL connection string to the App Configuration Service using Terraform?

Here is the complete file:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "01e15847-fdfc-4957-b995-b9e60d7ff59b"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "microservices-traning"
  location = "East US"
}


resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "serversqldavidmata"
  resource_group_name      = "microservices-traning"
  location                 = "East US"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "sql-server-dmv"
  resource_group_name          = "microservices-traning"
  location                     = "East US"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "david"
  administrator_login_password = "david"

  tags = {
    environment = "development"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "example" {
  name                = "FirewallRuleAll"
  resource_group_name = "microservices-traning"
  server_name         = "sql-server-dmv"
  start_ip_address    = "0.0.0.0"
  end_ip_address      = "255.255.255.255"
}

# 1.- Generating a variable with the connection string
output "database_name" {
  value = azurerm_sql_database.database.name,
  database_connection_string    = "Server=tcp:${module.database.name}.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=${module.database.database_name};Persist Security Info=False;User ID=${var.database_user};Password=${var.database_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
}


# 2.- By using local-exec command to get the connection string and then put it into the Azure App Config Service
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "example" {
  name                = "appConf1"
  resource_group_name = "microservices-traning"
  location            = "East US"
}

locals {
  config_mapping = {
    mykey = "myvalue",
    CONFIG_CN_ACCOUNT = "myvalue"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "example" {
  for_each = local.config_mapping

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az appconfig kv set --connection-string $CONNECTION_STRING --key $KEY --value $VALUE --yes"

    environment = {
      CONNECTION_STRING = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.primary_write_key.0.connection_string
      KEY               = each.key
      VALUE             = each.value
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `Azure SQL connection` string by using the below approach.

Providing the sample and working code for your reference,

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
...
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_plan" {
...
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "webapp" {
...
site_config {...}
app_settings = {
"SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
}

connection_string {
name = "Database"
type = "SQLAzure"
value = "Server=tcp:azurerm_sql_server.sqldb.fully_qualified_domain_name Database=azurerm_sql_database.db.name;User ID=azurerm_sql_server.sqldb.administrator_login;Password=azurerm_sql_server.sqldb.administrator_login_password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;"
 }
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "sqldb" {
name = var.sql_server_name
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
version = "12.0"
administrator_login = var.sql_admin_login
administrator_login_password = var.sql_admin_password
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "db" {
name = "terraform-sqldatabase20"
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
location = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
server_name = azurerm_sql_server.sqldb.name
}
```

***Reference:***

- Working code with [example](https://github.com/HoussemDellai/terraform-course/blob/main/05_Web_Sql_database/main.tf).
- Azure RM [AppService](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service) & [SQL database](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_database).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the `azurerm_app_configuration_key` resource?

```
resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "configuration_values" {
  for_each = local.config_mapping
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.example.id
  key = each.key
  value = each.value
}
```